# `errorStrategy` setting to stop current process but continue pipeline

Tags: nextflow

I have a lot of samples that go through a process which sometimes fail (deterministically). In such a case, I would want the failing process to stop, but all other samples to still get submitted and processed independently.

If I understand correctly, setting `errorStrategy 'ignore'` will continue the script within the failing process, which is not what I want. And `errorStrategy 'finish'` would stop submitting new samples, even though there is no reason for the other samples to fail too. And while `errorStrategy 'retry'` could technically work (by repeating the failing processes while the good ones get through), that doesn't seem like a good solution.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a process can fail deterministically, it might be better to handle this situation somehow. Setting the [errorStrategy](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#errorstrategy) directive to 'ignore' will mean any processes execution errors are ignored and allow your workflow continue. For example, you might get a process execution error if a process exits with a non-zero exit status or if one or more expected output files are missing. The pipeline will continue, however downstream processes will not be attempted.

Contents of `test.nf`:

```
nextflow.enable.dsl=2

process foo {

    tag { sample }

    input:
    val sample

    output:
    path "${sample}.txt"

    """
    if [ "${sample}" == "s1" ] ; then
        (exit 1)
    fi
    if [ "${sample}" == "s2" ] ; then
        echo "Hello" > "${sample}.txt"
    fi
    """
}

process bar {

    tag { txt }

    input:
    path txt

    output:
    path "${txt}.gz"

    """
    gzip -c "${txt}" > "${txt}.gz"
    """
}

workflow {

    Channel.of('s1', 's2', 's3') | foo | bar
}
```

Contents of `nextflow.config`:

```
process {

  // this is the default task.shell:
  shell = [ '/bin/bash', '-ue' ]

  errorStrategy = 'ignore'
}
```

Run with:

```
nextflow run -ansi-log false test.nf
```

Results:

```
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 20.10.0
Launching `test.nf` [drunk_bartik] - revision: e2103ea23b
[9b/56ce2d] Submitted process > foo (s2)
[43/0d5c9d] Submitted process > foo (s1)
[51/7b6752] Submitted process > foo (s3)
[43/0d5c9d] NOTE: Process `foo (s1)` terminated with an error exit status (1) -- Error is ignored
[51/7b6752] NOTE: Missing output file(s) `s3.txt` expected by process `foo (s3)` -- Error is ignored
[51/267685] Submitted process > bar (s2.txt)
```

Comment: I see, thank you! And if I'm not mistaken, the failing process (foo on s1 here) is guaranteed to stop at the first error because of the automatic `set -e`? In the case when the failure is not an `exit 1` but an error in an external program (so `foo` could continue running if there is no `set -e`).

Comment: @Alexlok Correct: `set -e` will exit immediately if a command exits with a non-zero status. I.e. Commands following this will not be run. Note that if you are piping commands together in your script, there's no guarantee unless you use `shell = [ '/bin/bash', '-euo', 'pipefail' ]`. Also note that I put `exit 1` inside of a subshell to simulate an external command. Without `set -e`, `foo` will continue and process s1 will fail in the same way as s3 does (i.e. Missing output files...)

Comment: Sorry, one aspect is still not fully clear to me: in your example, you added `set -ue` in the config file; iirc Nextflow automatically adds it to every file that gets run. And, (it seems to me through experimenting) the `errorStrategy 'ignore'` does not change that behavior?

Comment: @Alexlok No worries - I was just pointing out what the default shell is. The value of `process.shell` in the nextflow.config just becomes the shebang that gets used in each of the workdir `.command.sh` scripts. Your last point is also correct: setting `errorStrategy 'ignore'` will not change how the script is run. If the shebang is `#!/bin/bash -e`, i.e. `set -e`, the command script will still exit immediately if a command exits with a non-zero exit status, regardless of the errorStrategy. Note that you could do a `set +e` before your sometimes failing command to override it.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you!